# Need a shell script for spinning cursor

Tags: bash, shell

I need a shell script for spinning cursor which I can use with "copying" function. I tried below program and it works but the only problem I have here is that the spinner is showing below the text.

```
#!/bin/bash
spinner=('\' '/' '-' '\')

copy(){
echo "copying files..."
spin &
pid=$!
for i in `seq 1 10`
do 
sleep 1
done
kill $pid
echo ""
}

spin(){
while [ 1 ]
do 
for i in "${spinner[@]}"
do
echo -ne "\r$i"
sleep 0.2
done
done
}
copy
```

**Expected Output:** Copying files...\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

spinner () {
    local chars=('|' / - '\')

    # hide the cursor
    tput civis
    trap 'printf "\010"; tput cvvis; return' INT TERM

    printf %s "$*"

    while :; do
        for i in {0..3}; do
            printf %s "${chars[i]}"
            sleep 0.3
            printf '\010'
        done
    done
}

copy ()
{
    local pid return

    spinner 'Copying 5 files... ' & pid=$!

    # Slow copy command here
    sleep 4

    return=$?

   # kill spinner, and wait for the trap commands to complete
    kill "$pid"
    wait "$pid"

    if [[ "$return" -eq 0 ]]; then
        echo done
    else
        echo ERROR
    fi
}

copy
```

Depending on how you use this, you probably want to hide the cursor earlier, and show it later. Instead of turning it on and off for multiple `copy` or `spinner` invocations. Eg:

```
#!/bin/bash

trap 'tput cvvis' EXIT
tput civis

copy
copy
# other stuff
```

The cursor is hidden when `tput civis` runs, and un-hidden (`tput cvvis`) when the script exits (normally, or due to interrupt etc). If you do it like this, remove the corresponding `tput` commands from the function (but keep the other trap commands).

The reason for hiding the cursor is that it can mess with the spinner animation.

Comment: Thanks Dan, it worked as expected.

Comment: Just a little remark:

If you want a smooth animation: change ${chars[i]} by ${chars[i+1]}

Answer (score 0):

Print the text *Copying files...* without trailing newline, if you don't want one:

```
echo -n Copying files...
```